# Limit using definition in complex plane

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

I know that $$\lim\limits_{z \to i} \frac{z^2+1}{z}=0$$
But, I couldn't prove it using the definition of limit. Could you please help me?

Answer (score 0):

Let $z = x + \mathrm i y$ and consider the limits $y=1$ while $x \to 0$ and $x=0$ while $y \to 1$, separately.

In the case $z=x+\mathrm i$, where $x \to 0$ we get
$$\lim_{z \to \mathrm i}\frac{z^2+1}{z} = \lim_{x \to 0} \left[\frac{x(x^2+2)}{x^2+1} + \left(\frac{x^2}{x^2+1}\right)\mathrm i\right] = 0+0 \mathrm i$$

In the case $z=0+\mathrm i y$, where $y \to 1$, we get
$$\lim_{z \to \mathrm i}\frac{z^2+1}{z} = \lim_{y \to 1} \left[ 0
+\left(\frac{y^2-1}{y}\right)\mathrm i \right] = 0 + 0\mathrm i$$

Comment: Can we really use it? Because it mean the limit approach only from line y=1 and x=0. What about the other lines? What I want to do is to prove that for every ε>0, there is δ>0 such as if |z-i|<δ then |(z^2+1)/z|<ε.

Comment: You can try the same argument for $z=\mathrm i+r(\cos\theta + \mathrm i \sin \theta)$ and, as $r \to 0$, the limit tends to $0 + \mathrm i 0$, independently of $\theta$. Recall the derivation of the Cauchy Rieman equations only requires the limit in the real direction and the limit in the imaginary direction be equal.

Comment: Oh okay... but it's not using definition of limit ._. But I appreciate it... thanks ^^

Comment: @user379677 It does. Just use the $\varepsilon\delta$ argument on both the real and imaginary parts. That is straight-forward. Can you show that $(y^2-1)/y \to 0$ as $y \to 1$?

Answer (score 0):

Write that $|z^2+1|=|z+i||z-i|$ and use that $|z-i|<\delta$

Comment: I'm stuck with z under the fraction. I get that if |z-i|<1 then |z+i|<3 and |z|<2. But I still can't get rid of 1/|z|